# How to use startproject (django-admin.py) if there is already a django project?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to start a new django project (using `django-admin.py`) but unfortunately I'm always getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\NAME\dev\django>django-admin.py startproject foo
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]
[...]
```

The same applies to any other command of `django-admin.py` - every command does not exist.

I already have a django projects (in `C:\Users\NAME\dev\django\blog`) and I know that the startproject command is disabled if `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set, but when I try this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\os.py", line 423, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'
```

Or even better this:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> dir(settings)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 306, in __dir__
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 38, in _set up raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SE TTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

It seems that `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is undefined. Does anyone have an idea why I can't use `django-admin.py`?

*Django 1.2.3, Windows 7 (64bit)*

Comment: I think your problem (the first code-block) is unrelated to DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, as startproject shouldn't need it. Is there any other error message when you run startproject?

Comment: Why not delete the entire project directory completely and start over?  Why not start the project in a new directory?  Why mess around with this?  Why not delete everything or use a different directory?

Comment: @sykora Nothing, just the usage and a list with available commands (which are not working)... @S.Lott This happens in every directory, no matter if there is already a project or not. Even in C:\.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is only needed when you want to use django-admin.py with an existing Django project.
Your issue seems to be different, it seems like django-admin.py does not honor the command line parameters for some reason. Never tried it on Windows, but have you tried doing something like:

```
python django-admin.py startproject blog
```

Now I also see you saying you already have blog project in that folder. Why do you need to start project with the same name in the same folder then? Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried to get `django-admin.py` working. You are right, it just didn't take the command line parameters (for whatever reason). This works fine: `python C:\Python26\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject abc`